# Weblogic 12c: Import OSB jar file (sbconfig.jar) into ServiceBus 12c using WLST

Tags: weblogic, pipeline, weblogic12c, wlst

I am trying to create a script for a pipeline to deploy OSB jar file into OSB/Servicebus.

I have tried using ant-sca-deploy.xml but i see no effect on GUI.
Is there any way to do this using wlst commands?

How are you doing this in your Projects?

Comment: Can you try using WLST to deploy the sbconfig?

Comment: What are the commands for this? All i found is the ANT commands here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/dev.1111/e10224/sca_lifecycle.htm#SOASE10905

Comment: If you have access to Oracle Support try checking: Import OSB Projects Using WLST (Doc ID 2407065.1)

Answer (score 0):

OSB can be deployed using ANT or maven .you can also use python script alternatively.